# How to center react bootstrap modal?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am using the react boostrap modal and trying to position it evenly centered and currently i am specifying the `width` of the modal and then setting the margin-left on the `modal-dialog` class to `285px !important` which seems to work. But how do i make it so when the screen size goes below `xl` size, the margin should be `100px`.

Here is the link to the [codepen](https://codepen.io/nsieber/pen/grGpzW).

My CSS looks like this:-

```
 .modal-content {
   width: 1200px  
   }
 .modal-dialog {
   margin-left: 285px !important  
   }
  @media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
 .modal-dialog {
    margin-left: 100px !important
  }
}
```

Apparently, the media query doesn't seem to work. Or is there a way to set the modal **to always be centered regardless of the screen size**?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use flex it is a piece of cake:

```
div.fade.in.modal {
  display:flex !important;
}

.modal-dialog {
  margin: auto;
}
```

This will always center it vertically and horizontal.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working quite right, seems to push the modal to the right for some reason!!

Comment: It does work! I can't save your codepen. So I can't show you. Did you set it to normal css and remove all other css?

Comment: Yes i did, seems like there's a media query set up in my project that seems to be messing it up. But yeah the code seems to be working. btw what if i want to give some margin-top and bottom?

Comment: @TreeHuggerRick Yes it does work on codepen if you do it like this but other media queries can mess it up indeed.

Comment: Awesome. Quick and easy. accepting this as answer. Thank you :)

Comment: @TreeHuggerRick No problem and yes you can give it margin with flex but it will calculate it from the center. Flex is wonderful for this kind of stuff.

Answer (score 22):

You can just add the property `center` in Modal. For example:

```
<Modal
  size="lg"
  aria-labelledby="contained-modal-title-vcenter"
  centered
>
......
</Modal>
```

Also, you can read the documentation https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/modal/#modal-vertically-centered

I hope my answer will help you.

Comment: This is the correct approach. @Michelangelo 's approach is not a react-y approach. 
+1 to Norayr for using the API well.

Comment: I think it's the better approach. Use CSS instead of component's properties is dangerous IMO.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as it adheres to the documented React Bootstrap API (is not a workaround).

Answer (score 1):

In Bootstrap documentation, there are different styling options you could choose from. But particularly, this should solve your issues;

```
   <Modal
  {...props}
  size="lg"
  aria-labelledby="contained-modal-title-vcenter"
  centered
>
  <Modal.Header closeButton>
    <Modal.Title id="contained-modal-title-vcenter">
      Modal heading
    </Modal.Title>
  </Modal.Header>
  <Modal.Body>
    <h4>Centered Modal</h4>
    <p>
      Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Cras justo odio,
      dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Morbi leo risus, porta ac
      consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros.
    </p>
  </Modal.Body>
  <Modal.Footer>
    <Button onClick={props.onHide}>Close</Button>
  </Modal.Footer>
</Modal>
```